# Display progress bar for 'reg copy' command

Tags: powershell

I wonder I anyone has an idea how can I add progress bar for multiple `REG Copy` items please?

Explorer UI works fine with `Copy-Item` but does not work with `reg copy`.

The reg file I copy is quite chunky and takes a while to copy so I thought some sort of progress bar would help. This is the example of my script for which I try to get a progress bar for:

```
$TestPath = "Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers"
    if ( Test-Path -path $TestPath  )  {          
    reg copy "\\$SourceHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" "\\$DestHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /s /f | out-null
    }
    Else {
    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /f | out-null
    reg copy "\\$SourceHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" "\\$DestHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /s /f  | out-null
    }


    $TestPath = "Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers"
    if ( Test-Path -path $TestPath  )  {  
    reg copy "\\$SourceHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" "\\$DestHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /s /f | out-null
    }
    Else {
    reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /f | out-null
    reg copy "\\$SourceHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" "\\$DestHost\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers" /s /f | out-null
    }
...
```

Comment: `reg` is a command line program not a powershell command like `Copy-Item`. It's very unlikely to report its progress, so I doubt you will be able to get a meaningful progress bar when using it.

Answer (score 1):

We know loops can be inefficient, but sometimes there a necessary thing.
How about something like.

```
$TargetRegKeys = 'Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers',
'Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers'  

$TargetRegKeys | ForEach-Object -Begin {Clear-Host; $I = 0; $out = ""} -process { 
{
    # if ( Test-Path -path $_ ) { reg copy "\\$SourceHost\$_"  "\\$DestHost\$_" / s /f | out-null }
    # Else { reg copy "\\$SourceHost\$_"  "\\$DestHost\$_" / s /f | out-null }
}

$I = $I + 1
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

Write-Progress -Activity "$($TargetRegKeys.Count) registry keys to process" -Status "Progress:" -PercentComplete ($I / $TargetRegKeys.Count * 100)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
} -end {$out}
```

Of course the Sleeps are only there for testing, so one can see the progress bar. The 'If' is commented to avoid any changes to my environment.

Comment: See my answer for a different approach to providing a sequence that may need named properties for each operation.

Answer (score 0):

As like James C. already mentioned, `reg` doesn't support progress indicator. Powershell has, however, [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-5.1) that can be used. Like so,

```
write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 20
reg copy ...
write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 40
reg copy ...
write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 60
reg copy ...
write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 80
reg copy ...
```

In this particular case, you have to decide the steps and increments in manual a way. The completion steps are up to you, so maybe something like:

```
$TestPath = "Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers"
write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 20
if ( Test-Path -path $TestPath  )  {          
    reg copy ...
}
Else {
    reg add ...
    write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 25
    reg copy ...
}

write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 40
$TestPath = "Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers"
if ( Test-Path -path $TestPath  )  {  
    reg copy ...
}
Else {
    reg add ...
    write-progress -activity "Updating registry" -status "Working: " -percentComplete 50
    reg copy ...
}
```

Comment: If he has a loop, he can work on iterations of the command with the size of an array or something of that nature, but his method seems incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to parameterize your data a little bit you can use something similar to the following snippet.  The `CopyInfos` contain all of your parameters.  Presumably your inputs all follow a similar pattern name.  The first line is the property name for each copy operation.  The rest of the lines are pipe `(|)` delimited operations for each copy.  Using the suggestions above you can compute the percent complete based on your parameters.  From here you just need to plug in your correct parameters and build your correct strings for the `copy` and `add` functions.

```
$CopyInfos = ("Path1|Path2|Path3", `
    "Print\Providers|Source1|Destination", `
    "BowWowWow\Print\Providers|Source2|Destination2", `
    "Meow\Print\Providers|Source13|Destination3", `
    "Ow!\Print\Providers|Source14|Destination44", `
    "Wow6432Node\Print\Providers|Source15|Destination555" 
     ) | ConvertFrom-CSV -Delimiter "|"

$x = 0
foreach ($CopyInfo in $CopyInfos) {
  $percent = [int] (($x * 100) / $CopyInfos.Count)
  write-progress -Activity "$($CopyInfo.Path1)" -Status "Starting" -PercentComplete $Percent
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

  $x++
  $percent = [int] (($x * 100) / $CopyInfos.Count)
  write-progress -Activity "$($CopyInfo.Path1)" -Status "Finished" -PercentComplete $Percent
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Powershell 5.0 on the computer where you are running the commands you could do something like this.

```
$SourceSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SourceHost
$DestSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $DestHost

$RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers"
Copy-Item -FromSession $SourceSession -ToSession $DestSession -Path $RegPath -Destination $RegPath -Recurse -Force

Remove-PSSession $SourceSession
Remove-PSSession $DestSession
```

Assuming your source and destination computers stay the same you can reuse the same session variables until you're done.

Comment: v. 2.0 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Got an idea just don't know if can be used i this situation.

In the initial post I have 2 reg copy jobs,

Can they be wrapped under 1 something like

$AJob = {
Reg copy1 ... 
reg copy2 ... 
reg copy3 ...
... 
}

And then this $AJob is run thought GUI progress bar?